# Split Tag contents into paragraphs along nested <br> tags

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been stuck on the same problem for a day and a half now and nothing seems to work. I am parsing HTML files and extracting paragraphs of text. However, some pages are structured like this:

```html
<p>First paragraph. <br/>Second paragraph.<br/>Third paragraph</p>
```

My desired output is this:

```html
<p>First paragraph.</p>
<p>Second paragraph.</p>
<p>Third paragraph.</p>
```

I tried the BS4 [`replace_with`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) function but it doesn't seem to be working, as I get this error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = "<p>First paragraph. <br/>Second paragraph.<br/>Third paragraph</p>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
allparas = soup.find_all('p') #In the actual files there is more code

for p in allparas:
    if p.find_all(["br", "br/"]): #Some files don't have br tags
        for br in p.find_all(["br", "br/"]):
            new_p = br.new_tag('p', closed=True)
            br.replace_with(new_p)
```

The closest I've gotten is by replacing the tag with a string, but something seems to be going wrong with the encoding:

```py
if html.find_all(["br", "br/"]):
    for br in html.find_all(["br", "br/"]):
        br.replace_with("</p><p>")
        reslist = [p for p in html.find_all("p")]
        allparas = ''.join(str(p) for p in reslist) #Overwriting allparas here as I need it later
```

This works, but my print output is as follows:

```
<p>First paragraph.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Second paragraph.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Third paragraph.</p>
```

Something is going wrong with converting the string to a BS4 tag. Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would it with css selectors (just a personal preference). In any case, based exclusively on your sample html, you can do something like this:

```
for s in list(soup.strings):
    #wrap the text segments with a new tag
    s.wrap(soup.new_tag("p"))
for br in soup.select('br'):
    #remove the original br tags
    br.extract()
soup
```

Output should be your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

### Regular function

Here is an implementation, which handles arbitrary siblings tags of those `<br>` tags (not just strings):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag


def breaks_to_paragraphs(
    tag: Tag,
    soup: BeautifulSoup,
    recursive: bool = False,
) -> None:
    """
    If `tag` contains <br> elements, it is split into `<p>` tags instead.

    The `<br>` tags are removed from `tag`.
    If no `<br>` tags are found, this function does nothing.

    Args:
        tag:
            The `Tag` instance to mutate
        soup:
            The `BeautifulSoup` instance the tag belongs to (for `new_tag`)
        recursive (optional):
            If `True`, the function is applied to all nested tags recursively;
            otherwise (default) only the children are affected.
    """
    elements = []
    contains_br = False
    for child in list(tag.children):
        if isinstance(child, Tag) and child.name != "br":
            if recursive:
                breaks_to_paragraphs(child, soup, recursive=recursive)
            elements.append(child)
        elif not isinstance(child, Tag):  # it is a `NavigableString`
            elements.append(child)
        else:  # it is a `<br>` tag
            contains_br = True
            p = soup.new_tag("p")
            child.replace_with(p)
            p.extend(elements)
            elements.clear()
    if elements and contains_br:
        p = soup.new_tag("p")
        tag.append(p)
        p.extend(elements)
    soup.smooth()
```

---

### Subclass method

Alternatively, since you need the original `BeautifulSoup` instance for calling the [`new_tag`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring-and-new-tag) method, you can also subclass it and implement this as a method instead:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag


class CustomSoup(BeautifulSoup):
    def breaks_to_paragraphs(self, tag: Tag, recursive: bool = False) -> None:
        """
        If `tag` contains <br> elements, it is split into `<p>` tags instead.

        The `<br>` tags are removed from `tag`.
        If no `<br>` tags are found, this method does nothing.

        Args:
            tag:
                The `Tag` instance to mutate
            recursive (optional):
                If `True`, the function is applied to all nested tags recursively;
                otherwise (default) only the children are affected.
        """
        elements = []
        contains_br = False
        for child in list(tag.children):
            if isinstance(child, Tag) and child.name != "br":
                if recursive:
                    self.breaks_to_paragraphs(child, recursive=recursive)
                elements.append(child)
            elif not isinstance(child, Tag):  # it is a `NavigableString`
                elements.append(child)
            else:  # it is a `<br>` tag
                contains_br = True
                p = self.new_tag("p")
                child.replace_with(p)
                p.extend(elements)
                elements.clear()
        if elements and contains_br:
            p = self.new_tag("p")
            tag.append(p)
            p.extend(elements)
        self.smooth()
```

---

### Demo

Here is a quick test:

```py
...

def main() -> None:
    html = """
    <p>
        First paragraph. <br/>
        Second paragraph.<br/> 
        <span>foo</span>
        <span>bar<br>baz</span>
    </p>
    """
    soup = CustomSoup(html, "html.parser")
    soup.breaks_to_paragraphs(soup.p)
    print(soup.p.prettify())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```html
<p>
 <p>
  First paragraph.
 </p>
 <p>
  Second paragraph.
 </p>
 <p>
  <span>
   foo
  </span>
  <span>
   bar
   <br/>
   baz
  </span>
 </p>
</p>
```

If you call it with `soup.breaks_to_paragraphs(soup.p, recursive=True)` instead:

```html
<p>
 <p>
  First paragraph.
 </p>
 <p>
  Second paragraph.
 </p>
 <p>
  <span>
   foo
  </span>
  <span>
   <p>
    bar
   </p>
   <p>
    baz
   </p>
  </span>
 </p>
</p>
```

Notice how it split into `<p>` tags along the nested `<br>` here as well.